# CodeIgniter Oracle select - random issue

Tags: oracle, codeigniter

I'm having a very weird problem with a quite simple select statement. Here it is:

I'm reading a csv file (that is an export of an Excel file). Field separator is ";" and each field is enclosed with "".

I use the second, third and fifth fields to create a SELECT to look for that information in the DB. In other words, I'm looking for people in a table according to their last and first names and, email. For example:

```
SELECT MAX(n_id_persona) AS n_id_persona 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT MAX(p.n_id_persona) AS n_id_persona
    FROM PERSONAS p
    WHERE (NO_ACCENTS(p.d_apellidos) LIKE NO_ACCENTS('%Lastname%') 
        AND NO_ACCENTS(p.d_nombres) LIKE NO_ACCENTS('%Firstname%'))
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT MAX(p.n_id_persona) AS n_id_persona
    FROM PERSONAS p
    LEFT JOIN CORREOS c ON (p.n_id_persona = c.n_id_persona)
    WHERE ((c.c_correo LIKE '%email@host.com%')) );
```

The issue is that, randomly, CodeIgniter does not bring any N_ID_PERSONA but if I test the same query in Oracle SQL Developer it retrieves and ID.

I first thought it was a timeout, but is discarded. Also, reformulated the queries because I thought they were not correct but nop. The function NO_ACCENTS() just replaces all accented characters by the corresponding letter and writes everything in uppercase. I also tried without using this NO_ACCENTS() function and got the same weird result.

Any ideas? Does this happen to anyone?

Thanks a lot!

V

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Here it is the code:

controllers/importador.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    session_start();
}

public function index()
{
    //Connection info to the DB

    $_SESSION['c'] = $connection_info;

    $this->db = $this->load->database($_SESSION['c'], TRUE, TRUE);
    $this->load->model('Importador_model');

    //Reads the csv
    $this->load->library('csvreader');

    $filePath = '/home/vcl/Desktop/CRM/File_name.csv';

    $data['csvData'] = $this->csvreader->parse_file($filePath);

    foreach($data['csvData'] as $linea){

        $data['coincidencia'] = $this->Importador_model->Buscar_contacto(str_replace('\'', '\'\'', $linea['Apellido']), str_replace('\'', '\'\'', $linea['Nombre']), $linea['Email']);  

        echo $linea['Apellido'].' '.$linea['Nombre'].''.$linea['Entrevista'].'<br>';
        $temp = $data['coincidencia']->row();
        echo $temp->N_ID_PERSONA;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

models/importador_model.php

```
function Buscar_contacto($ape = NULL, $nom = NULL, $email = NULL) 
{
$CI =& get_instance();

$query = $CI->db->query('SELECT MAX(n_id_persona) AS n_id_persona 
             FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT MAX(p.n_id_persona) AS n_id_persona
                FROM PERSONAS p
                WHERE (NO_ACCENTS(p.d_apellidos) LIKE NO_ACCENTS(\'%'.$ape.'%\') 
                    AND NO_ACCENTS(p.d_nombres) LIKE NO_ACCENTS(\'%'.$nom.'%\'))
                UNION
                SELECT DISTINCT MAX(p.n_id_persona) AS n_id_persona
                FROM PERSONAS p
                LEFT JOIN CORREOS c ON (p.n_id_persona = c.n_id_persona)
                WHERE ((c.c_correo LIKE \'%'.$email.'%\')) )');

return $query;
}
```

Does it help a little more?

Comment: When you say "randomly" do you mean for the _same_ parameters you sometimes get data and sometimes you get no data? What does your Codeigniter PHP code that calls this SQL look like?

Comment: Is, for example, 1 of this case out of 20. It is supposed to retrieve data but it doesn't. But for other cases the same query works perfectly well.

Comment: I'm editing the question with the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

you could use "trim" function, sometimes you can have white spaces between your testing condictions, try somthing like this:

SELECT...

```
WHERE TRIM((NO_ACCENTS(p.d_apellidos)) LIKE TRIM(NO_ACCENTS('%Lastname%')) 
    AND TRIM(NO_ACCENTS(p.d_nombres)) LIKE TRIM(NO_ACCENTS('%Firstname%')))
```

note that i have added trim in the table field (p.d_apelidos) and did the same in (no_accents('%Lastname%'))